# I am trying to install 8192eu driver on Ubuntu 20.04.01, after following every guide and forum I can find it is still not coming up on my driver list

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubuntu

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04.01 and am trying to install the correct driver for my TP-LINK TL WN-821N, there is a popular [github repo](https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver) for it that I have followed and is basically the only answer to every question surrounding this driver. The only problem I can see is that when I 'make' from the directory of the driver some fallthrough's occur.

Ubuntu is detecting the adapter, the driver is just not coming up on lsmod.

lsusb:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0cf3:e500 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:2115 Acer, Inc Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2357:0107 TP-Link TL-WN821N Version 5 RTL8192EU
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"vodafone06378B"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.54 GHz  Access Point: D6:35:1D:06:37:93   
      Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=27 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-33 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:68   Missed beacon:0
```

lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ccm                    20480  9
rfcomm                 81920  16
cmac                   16384  3
algif_hash             16384  1
algif_skcipher         16384  1
af_alg                 24576  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   24576  2
snd_hda_codec_realtek   122880  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
joydev                 24576  0
snd_acp3x_pdm_dma      16384  1
snd_soc_dmic           16384  1
acp3x_rn               16384  1
snd_hda_intel          53248  4
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_soc_core          245760  3 acp3x_rn,snd_soc_dmic,snd_acp3x_pdm_dma
snd_hda_codec         131072  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
snd_pcm               106496  7 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_acp3x_pdm_dma,snd_pcm_dmaengine
btusb                  57344  0
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
btintel                24576  1 btusb
uvcvideo               98304  0
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
ath10k_pci             49152  0
bluetooth             581632  41 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
edac_mce_amd           32768  0
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       49152  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
kvm_amd                98304  0
videodev              225280  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
ccp                    86016  1 kvm_amd
ath10k_core           475136  1 ath10k_pci
input_leds             16384  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
mc                     53248  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
wmi_bmof               16384  0
serio_raw              20480  0
ecc                    28672  1 ecdh_generic
hid_multitouch         28672  0
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
kvm                   663552  1 kvm_amd
ath                    36864  1 ath10k_core
k10temp                16384  0
snd                    90112  23 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
mac80211              843776  1 ath10k_core
rtsx_pci_ms            24576  0
snd_rn_pci_acp3x       20480  0
snd_pci_acp3x          16384  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
soundcore              16384  1 snd
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
ideapad_laptop         20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  1
cfg80211              704512  3 ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
parport_pc             40960  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
amdgpu               4579328  31
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdgpu
gpu_sched              32768  1 amdgpu
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu
hid_generic            16384  0
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         28672  0
aesni_intel           372736  10
ttm                   106496  1 amdgpu
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 amdgpu
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
nvme                   49152  2
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   491520  12 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,ttm
i2c_piix4              28672  0
nvme_core             102400  4 nvme
rtsx_pci               73728  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,rtsx_pci_ms
wmi                    32768  2 wmi_bmof,ideapad_laptop
i2c_hid                28672  0
video                  49152  1 ideapad_laptop
hid                   131072  3 i2c_hid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic
```

I am pretty much a newbie when it comes to linux so don't go too harsh

Edit: I didnt really find a solution to my problem, but instead of using kubuntu I just changed to normal ubuntu as I am having less issues, it just happens that it has also fixed my driver issues

Comment: According to your `iwconfig` output your Wi-Fi adapter `wlp2s0` already works.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov hello again, after what you said on my previous post I decided to switch to dual boot and Ubuntu since I was using Kali for no reason. My wlp2so I’m pretty sure is my built in WiFi card

Comment: What steps did you take to install the driver?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I followed all the steps that are in the README of the GitHub repo I linked

Comment: Did one of the steps give an error?  I see there's a camera on usb bus 001.  Does that one work?  What do you get from "modprobe 8192eu; dmesg | tail" ?  After the switch to Ubuntu, did you repeat the installation?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille give me a little while I now cannot load up the desktop, it is just all greyed out permanently